# Modify svg rect ID with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am in the process of making an interactive clock where the user clicks to add their own image on but I have become a bit stuck and even after a couple of hours trying all sorts of things I still cannot figure it out so hopefully someone can help me or point me in the right direction. I am also new to using SVG as well. This is how the SVG code looks:

```
        <g id="Layer_3">
        <rect id="clickable9" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 9, 54, 360)" x="54" y="360" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable8" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 8, 91.702, 518.706)" x="91.702" y="518.706" transform="matrix(0.866 -0.5 0.5 0.866 -270.127 155.285)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable7" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 7, 203.706, 637.298)" x="203.706" y="637.298" transform="matrix(0.5 -0.866 0.866 0.5 -473.1227 581.123)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable6" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 6, 360, 684)" x="360" y="684" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable5" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 5, 518.706, 646.298)" x="518.706" y="646.298" transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 258.2894 1567.7191)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable4" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 4, 637.298, 534.294)" x="637.298" y="534.294" transform="matrix(-0.866 -0.5 0.5 -0.866 1008.1263 1464.7147)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable3" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 3, 684, 378)" x="684" y="378" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>         
        <rect id="clickable2" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 2, 646.298, 219.294)" x="646.298" y="219.294" transform="matrix(-0.866 0.5 -0.5 -0.866 1464.7146 172.1181)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable1" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 1, 534.294, 100.701)" x="534.294" y="100.701" transform="matrix(-0.5 0.866 -0.866 -0.5 1037.7107 -271.7195)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable12" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 12, 378, 54)" x="378" y="54" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable11" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 11, 219.294, 91.702)" x="219.294" y="91.702" transform="matrix(0.5 0.866 -0.866 0.5 275.1223 -167.123)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
        <rect id="clickable10" onClick="buttonClick(evt, 10, 378, 54)" x="100.702" y="203.706" transform="matrix(0.866 0.5 -0.5 0.866 155.2847 -46.1193)" fill="#4BB749" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="126" height="126"/>
    </g>
```

This is what I have for on click part:

```
    function buttonClick(evt, clocknumber, xpos, ypos)
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("uploadedFiles");
        alert('You clicked clock number: ' + clocknumber);
        $('#uploadedFiles').trigger('click');
        var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
        svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'height','126');
        svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'width','126');
        svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','test.png');
        svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'x',xpos);
        svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'y',ypos);
        svgimg.setAttributeNS(null,'visibility','visible');
        $('svg').append(svgimg);
    }
```

I managed to create a test PNG file on top but I don't think this is ideal at all. How would I add/change the SVG? Also... How would I make it so that it remains clickable when the SVG is changed? With the test PNG image it stops it from being clickable after that. I should be able to do the file upload part myself but was having trouble changing it to the image uploaded.

Comment: This is not a working example. What/where is the element with id uploadedFiles?

Comment: Not needed. I can do that myself but I need some way of getting the ID of the rect so I can apply an image to it. I can't seem to be able to use the normal getElementById with svg but hopefully there is another way?

Comment: getElementById works fine for SVG just the same as HTML. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
svgimg.setAttribute('pointer-events','none');
```

Then the image will be transparent to clicks, and the rectangle beneath it will still receive the click.